# Pushing a template function pointer into a list

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template function, whose address I wish to push into a list of function pointers.

What I have is:

```
typedef void (*NavFunc)(int);
std::list<NavFunc> List;

template<class T>void Func(int) {  //Matches NavFunc-Declaration
    List.push_back(&Func<T>);
    //doOtherStuff
}
```

This throws me an error

```
No match found for _STL::list<void (*)(int),_STL::allocator<void (*)(int)> >::push_back(void (*)(int))
```

However if I do:

```
template<class T>void Func(int) {  //Matches NavFunc-Declaration
    NavFunc F = &Func<T>;
    List.push_back(F);
    //doOtherStuff
}
```

it works perfectly fine...what I don't get right now is the 'why'. Shouldn't it work just as well, if I don't use a buffer variable?

I'm currently using BCB 6 under Windows, I don't know how it would behave under g++.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The original code works with g++ and clang. BCB 6 is, what, 12 years old now?

Comment: "I don't know how it would behave under g++" - just fine: http://ideone.com/9bimoz. The 'why' is that you're using a dodgy decades-old compiler. Do you really need to do that?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Unfortunately, yes. At least as of right now. If we're lucky, we get to migrate to a newer compiler soon. But thanks for pointing to ideone, I keep forgetting about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works fine in `gcc-4.8.2`.

I'm guessing it's a problem with BCC 6?

```
#include <list>

typedef void (*NavFunc)(int);
std::list<NavFunc> List;

template<class T>
void Func(int)
{
    List.push_back(&Func<T>);
}

int main()
{
    Func<int>(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably. BCC is known to be sort of buggy at times. Thanks for taking the time.